# How to share a Facebook post with FBWebDialogs using only the post id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I see from the [FBWebDialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBWebDialogs#presentDialogModallyWithSession%3adialog%3aparameters%3ahandler%3a) docs that you can pass in a 'link' parameter *(hyperlink to external content)* to share with Facebook. But in my app I don't have hyperlinks -- I only have the 'id' of a given facebook post that I wish to re-share.

**Q: How to share a Facebook post if you only have the post id?**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution that worked for me. Essentially you need to build a permalink binding the USER_ID and POST_ID and pass that permalink as one of the params:

```
#import "Facebook.h"
    // ...

        // Facebook ID is provided in form {USER_ID}_{POST_ID}
        NSString *rawId = @"113418445354091_460428417431691";

        // Explode the ID into an array with two elements
        NSArray *idArray = [rawId componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];

        // Build the permalink and bind the USER_ID and _POST_ID
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=%@&v=wall&story_fbid=%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:0],[idArray objectAtIndex:1]];

        // Build params dict
        NSDictionary *params = @{
                       @"access_token" : @"MY_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN",
                       @"name"         : @"My Post Name",
                       @"description"  : @"My Post Description hello there how are you.",
                       @"link"         : path
                       };


        // Call the Dialog
        [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error){}
    }];


    // ...
```